# Unfair Coin and the distribution of X

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For an unfair coin, let $X$ be the number of trials needed for one heads and at least 1 tails. Find the distribution of X.

My attempt: 
the sample space would look like $$\{HT\}, \{T,H\}, \{T,T,H\}, \{T,H,T\}...\{T,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,.........H\}\\$$
To me it look like the the probability of $X$ would be $$P(N=X)=\binom{N}{1}(p)(q)^{N-1}$$
Where $N$ is the number of trials. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Perhaps I just don't understand the question at all.

Comment: As stated the question does not make sense, unless I am misreading something. (How is $X$ defined if you get two heads in your first two flips?) Should it read "at least one heads and at least one tails"?

Comment: Assuming you mean at least one heads and at least one tails, note that $\{T,H,T\}$ would never happen since in that example you are done after the second toss and would not have had any reason to toss a third time.  Note: *every* outcome is either of the form $\underbrace{HHH\cdots H}_{n\geq 1~\text{heads}}T$ or of the form $\underbrace{TTT\cdots T}_{n\geq 1~\text{tails}}H$

Comment: I do not mean at least for both. I mean exactly 1 head and at least 1 Tails. so, $$\{H,T\}, \{T,H\},\{T,T, ......, H\}$$

Comment: Would the sample space be the distribution of X?

Comment: The sample space would be HT, TH, TTH, TTTH,.... Then $P(X = 2) = P(HT) + P(TH)$ while $P(X = n) = P(T \cdots TH)$ for $n \geq 3.$

Comment: One issue is that one-fourth of the time, a fair coin yields HH and is immediately lost.  So one question is whether and how the probability distribution of $X$ should take that into account.  Should it be conditioned on the sequence falling into the sample space (and then all probabilities are scaled upward by $4/3$), or should there be an atom somewhere to indicate failure, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets restate the problem for clarity. A coin has a probability of heads p and tails q.
We toss the coin until the first time that we obtain exactly one head and at least one tail.  Let the random variable X = n if this occurs for the first time on trial n>=2. Find the probability distribution of X.

Answer.  When n=2 the possible outcomes are 00,01,10,11 where 1 represents heads and 0 represents tails.  These occur with probability ${p^2},pq,qp,{q^2}$ respectively. If the outcome is either 01 or 10 then, X=2.  BUT notice that if the outcome of two tosses is 11, we have "game over" because it is no longer possible to obtain exactly one head in any further tosses. Because of this we also define X = 0 if the outcome is 11.  We now have $\begin{array}{l}
P(X = 0) = {p^2}\\
P(X = 1) = 0\\
{\rm{ }}P(X = 2) = P(01 \cup 10) = 2pq.
\end{array}$

The outcomes for 3 tosses are 000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111.  Notice that 000,001,010,011, etc., cannot occur because the experiment would end after two tosses in each of those cases. The only successful case for n=3 is 110 which occurs with probability $p{q^2}$. At this point it is easy to see that $P(X = n) = p{q^{n - 1}},{\rm{ }} {\rm{ }}n \ge 3.$

This completes the probability assignments and answers the question provided we can show $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {P\left( {X = n} \right)}  = 1.{\rm{ }}$  We begin by considering the (geometric) series
$\sum\limits_{n = 3}^\infty  {P\left( {X = n} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{n = 3}^\infty  {p{q^{n - 1}}}  = p{q^2}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{q^n}}  = \frac{{p{q^2}}}{{1 - q}}{\rm{  }}(0 < q < 1) = {q^2}.$

It follows that $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {P\left( {X = n} \right)}  = {p^2} + 2pq + {q^2} = {\left( {p + q} \right)^2} = 1.$